# Process builder returns exit code 127 when running a Kshell script

Tags: java, process, runtime.exec, processbuilder

I am trying to run a Kshell script via Java process builder. The script itself works perfectly when run on the server. However, when I run it via process builder I am getting exit code `127 - command not found`.

Code:

```
ProcessBuilder procBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
procBuilder.directory(new File(codeDir));
proc = procBuilder.start();
errorCode = proc.waitFor();

return errorCode;
```

My command look like:

```
[/bin/ksh, -c, myscript.ksh, 20150714]
```

I run the script on the server by itself using following command:

```
ksh -x myscript.ksh 20150714
```

any idea what is going on wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure the `myscript.ksh` is in the `codeDir`?

Comment: Yea, I do have the script there. I am considering using common-exec. Hope it solve these problem.

Comment: And are you positive that `ksh` is at `/bin/ksh`?

Comment: Yea, I checked it. It's there, it's so pain to having to do all these. So I tried common-exec and it worked in the first try. What a relief. Thanks for your help tho, appreciate it.. :)

Comment: I have the exact same problem on one server only... Could not figure out why. Using common-exec is not an option, because it lacks the advanced features I need...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gave up on procesbuilder and tried [common-exec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/index.html) and it worked perfectly. Here is my updated code:

```
CommandLine cmdLine = CommandLine.parse(command);

for (String comm : cmd)
{
    cmdLine.addArgument(comm);
}

DefaultExecutor exec = new DefaultExecutor();
exec.setExitValue(0);
exec.setWorkingDirectory(new File(codeDir));
exitCode = exec.execute(cmdLine);
```

Hope it help someone in the future.

Comment: I had similar experience with process builder and started using common-exec.

Answer (score 1):

ProcessBuilder does so because it does not find your script on PATH. Just execute the command echo $PATH with ProcessBuilder. You will see that 'its' PATH is different.